# can ansible ask for passwords automatically and only if necessary

Tags: ansible

So `ansible-playbook` has `--ask-pass` and `--ask-sudo-pass`. Is there a way to get ansible to try ssh without a password first and then only prompt for a password if passwordless login fails? Similarly, can ansible try sudo without a password first and then only prompt if that doesn't work?

FYI I have a little shell function to try to figure this out by trial and error, but I'm hoping something like this is baked into ansible.

```
get_ansible_auth_args() {
  local base_check="ansible all --one-line --inventory-file=deploy/hosts/localhost.yml --args=/bin/true --sudo"
  ${base_check}
  if [[ $? -eq 0 ]]; then
    return;
  fi
  local args="--ask-pass"
  ${base_check} ${args}
  if [[ $? -eq 0 ]]; then
    export ANSIBLE_AUTH_ARGS="${args}"
    return;
  fi
  local args="--ask-pass --ask-sudo-pass"
  ${base_check} ${args}
  if [[ $? -eq 0 ]]; then
    export ANSIBLE_AUTH_ARGS="${args}"
    return;
  fi
}
```

Comment: I could be mistaken, but I believe ansible SSH in non-interactive mode and needs to know upfront so that it can adjust its connection parameters.

Comment: Even as of ansible 1.6.6 I still don't think this is a feature. It doesn't even allow different passwords per host yet (on the prompt - can set different passwords in the hosts file). You could probably raise this a feature.

Comment: @Peter Lyons - Such a feature would be useful to me too. Just checked with ansible folks what if they have a recommended way of requesting a feature, after reading through their community guides. - https://twitter.com/smprk/status/576414667913969664 A github issue would seem like cluttering their queue.

Answer (score 1):

If you set `ask_pass` and `ssh_args` as I show below then ansible should ask you for password at the beginning once and use that password whenever public key auth doesn't work.

```
[defaults]
ask_pass      = True

[ssh_connection]
ssh_args = -o PubkeyAuthentication=yes -o PasswordAuthentication=yes -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s
```

This is still not the full solution: Catch being (AFAIK) ansible uses `sshpass`, so the password it collected from your at the start would be the only password it would use and it won't work if you have different passwords for different machines. :-)

Only other hack I can think of is to replace `/usr/bin/ssh` (or whichever is your openssh's ssh used by ansible) with a script of your own that wraps the logic of reading password from some flat file if needed, I suspect ansible would hide the `tty` so your script won't be able to 'read' the password from stdin.

Comment: At maximum, this only helps for the SSH password, not for the become/sudo password.